# Microsoft SQL Query where value from text file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, text, input

I would like to be able to input all my 'where =' values from a text file instead of manually typing them in the query editor...

i.e. instead of having a bunch of where statements (see first example below), have a single where clause the uses a text file for filter values (see second example below).

**example 1**

```
Select *
From table1
WHERE
(Email_Address = 'blah@blah.com') OR 
(Email_Address = 'blah@blah.com') OR 
(Email_Address = 'blah@blah.com') OR 
(Email_Address = 'blah@blah.com') OR 
(Email_Address = 'blah@blah.com') OR 
(Email_Address = 'blah@blah.com')
```

**example 2**

```
Select * 
From table1
WHERE
(Email_Address = 'c:\temp\emails.txt')
```

.......

Comment: For that to work, you need to do something like bulk insert to load the values from your emails.txt into a table first.. and then your where statement can be like.. where email_address in (select distinct  email_address from your_bulk_insert_table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I use to do this is to Right click the Database and import emails as a new table.

I then use the Like function to compare two tables like so:

```
use Database

SELECT  Email FROM Emails
JOIN EmailToLookFor ON Emails LIKE EmailsToLookFor.Email + '%'
```

In this example EmailsToLookFor is the new table you imported and Emails is the table to search in,
in both tables Email is the field containing the emails; if you wish to search for more information relating to the found email addresses ass is as:

```
SELECT  Email, Username, Name etc. FROM Emails
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

You could use an IN clause if your email addresses are easily pasted into your query

```
Select *
From table1
WHERE Email_Address IN ('email1@blah.com', 'email2@blah.com', 'email3@blah.com', 'email4@blah.com')
```

Comment: The OP specifically says they don't want to have to type out the e-mail addresses manually !